# Use 5.0V instead of 3.3V with the Raspberry Pi GPIO 'in' pins

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Is it possible to use the GPIO pins with 5V instead of 3.3V without destroying the Raspberry Pi? I need to handle window contacts in python, which needs 5V to work properly.

Greetings
Epileptic_Software

Comment: A (voltage) level-shifter chip can convert a 3.3V signal to 5V and vice-versa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have some experience using Raspberry GPIOs. You can not control the 5V pins, there are always set as high. Only 3.3V pins can be controlled. If you need 5V you can create a electric circuit with a relay that activates with 3.3V.

Hope this can be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I ment if I can set 5V on a GPIO pin without destroying the Pi.

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: It is my understanding that if you send 5V into the 3.3V GPIO pins you will destroy, at the very least, the GPIO portion of the SoC and fry those GPIOs forever.  You may even destroy the whole SoC and entirely brick the Pi.